# Jackson deserialization is very slow

Tags: java, android, json

I'm writing android java application (minSdkVersion 15) to get university timetable from php-site through api in json format. After creating InflaterInputStream i pass it to Jackson's ObjectMapper.readValue

```
result = mapper.readValue(inputStream, Timetable.class);
```

Source can be found here:
https://github.com/BesuglovS/Timetable/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/besuglovs/nu/timetable/app/MainActivity.java#L115

It takes about 4 hours to deserialize 4.265.362 bytes UTF-8 to this class.

```
public class Timetable {
    public List<Auditorium> auditoriums;
    public List<Calendar> calendars;
    public List<Discipline> disciplines;
    public List<Lesson> lessons;
    public List<Ring> rings;
    public List<Student> students;
    public List<StudentGroup> studentGroups;
    public List<StudentsInGroups> studentsInGroups;
    public List<Teacher> teachers;
    public List<TeacherForDiscipline> teacherForDisciplines;

    public List<ConfigOption> configOptions;
    public List<LessonLogEvent> lessonLogEvents;
}
```

All subclasses are very simple. Like this.

```
public class Auditorium {
    public Integer AuditoriumId;
    public String Name;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, can you try [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) ?

Comment: Just to be clear: 4 hours to deserialize ~4mb of data?

Comment: I will try GSON as soon as i can.
Yes. That what makes me sad. 4 hours to execute this one line.

Comment: Why did you get a byte array at all? You should have just fed the `InflaterInputStream` to `ObjectMapper.readValue()` directly.

Comment: About byte array. It was a typo.
I pass it directly there.

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is on the receiving side? It could also be the sender generating the JSON.

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. I've tried to write stream contents to file.
It was very fast and with right content.

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is deserialization and not the network?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. I've tried to read content from stream and write it to the internal file. All went fast & well. File was correct JSON.

Comment: This is the line that excutes forever:
https://github.com/BesuglovS/Timetable/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/besuglovs/nu/timetable/app/MainActivity.java#L104

Comment: I've tried Gson with the same effect.

4Mb + 40 minutes with no result or exception

Comment: Hey, did this story get a happy ending? Please share a solution here if you found it already! Thanks

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: First I went with manual JsonParser.
Then switch to Retrofit.
Eventually I go with React Native.